# How do I add a Steam library folder that's in a separate drive?

Tags: steam

I have about a terabyte's worth of games in a separate drive, and I just installed Ubuntu to my SSD and with the new Steam Proton software, I want to activate those downloads instead of redownloading everything. Can I get some help?

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty easily solved via some googling but I'll throw out what I think off the top of my head having done this on Windows.

The biggest thing you'll need to do is find where your external drive is mounted, and make sure you have read-write access. If the drive is NTFS formatted you will probably need to make sure [ntfs 3g](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NTFS-3G) is set up and running as opposed to the kernel drivers. I also have no idea how proton works but in normal steam you'll then need to go to `settings > downloads` and configure the drive as a source for games.